# ImageView Only Appears When Setting Background in XML - Not Using Picasso

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, picasso

I have a somewhat strange situation. I have an ImageView (ImageView1) which should be populated with an image using Picasso:

```
ImageView imageItem = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Picasso.with(this).load(boxart)
                .fit().centerInside().into(imageItem);
```

For some strange reason - the ImageView does not populate when using just Picasso - but as soon as I add a background via XML: android:background="@drawable/boxart"  they both show up - which I don't understand.

XML:

http://pastebin.com/yUxxaXqL

ScreenShot:

```
With android:background="@drawable/boxart" - http://imgur.com/7nMvDCT
Without android:background="@drawable/boxart" - http://imgur.com/UNQowhP
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: what are you passing the value to boxart, the url of image needs to be passed in the load parameter

Comment: add how you are adding image in Picasso. menas "boxart" ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks similar to this other issues: https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/457

Since you are using `wrap_content`, and initially don't have any content on your imageView, it renders with height=0
When loading the image with picasso, you set `fit()`, which adjusts the new image to the ImageView size. But since its height was 0, nothing renders.

Some things you can do:

1. If you are using an older version, update picasso to the latest version.
2. Make your ImageView match_parent to the desired size.